# Есть простые примеры реализации epoll на C/C++?

Tags: c++, сокет, epoll

Настраиваю неблокирующие сокеты... Читаю/отправляю небольшие посылки... А вот когда дело касается больших пакетов, то, как я понимаю, нужно использовать epoll. Не подскажите простенькие примеры чтения и записи с помощью epoll на с/с++?

Comment: Уже отвечал как-то на подобный вопрос. Кое-что можете посмотреть [тут](http://pastebin.com/vbMLKhrB) / IMHO не  очень сложно, при желании разберетесь. / А вообще можно начать с чтения `man 7 epoll`

Comment: epoll не поможет Вам решить задачу с отваливающимися клиентами. Честно. (я просто помню о предыдущем вопросе).

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите, для начала, в сторону libev или libevent. Во первых: получите некий уровень абстракции, во вторых - кроссплатформенность, в третьих - со временем понатыкаетесь на косяки и разберётесь в нюансах и epoll и kqueue и т.д.

Ну а пример: http://doc.dvgu.ru/devel/ev.html там сразу документация с него и начинается.

Если же хочется именно epoll, то откройте страницы руководств:

- http://manned.org/epoll.7 - это поможет разобраться со структурой и вообще архитектурой epoll, ответит на частые вопросы (FAQ) и покажет простой пример.
- http://manned.org/epoll_create.2 - это научит создавать инстанс epoll
- http://manned.org/epoll_ctl.2 - это научит добавлять, удалять и модифицировать файловые дескрипторы в epoll
- http://manned.org/epoll_wait.2 - ну а это научит ждать пачки событий.

Ну и другие примеры:

- http://nikcode.blogspot.ru/2013/02/linux-epoll.html - мало и по делу.
- http://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/epoll_intro.txt.html кода много, но больше - комментарии и пустые строки.

А вообще, как только вы сталкиваетесь с асинхронностью в любом её проявлении, будте готовы, что просто не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Простых примеров использования `epoll` не существует. Используйте [`boost::asio`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html).

Comment: Уже отказался не помню по каким причинам от boost::asio. Что-то не понравилось... Что разве всё так сложно?

Comment: Сам по себе ввод-вывод не сложен. Но вот тот факт, что сообщение в протоколе TCP может приходить "кусками" - и так же уходить - довольно надоедлив. В блокирующем режиме можно хотя бы цикл поставить...

Comment: @sitev_ru, ничего особо сложного в epoll нет.

Comment: Разбираюсь вот... Может скинете простенький примерчик? Вдруг поможет?

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос ещё актуален посмотрите по следующей [ссылке](http://nikcode.blogspot.ru/2013/02/linux-epoll.html)

Простая реализация [epoll сервера](https://github.com/dreambrother/example-apps/tree/master/c-epoll-server) К сожалению код по ссылке недоступен

Приведу код в ответе:

```
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/epoll.h> 

#define MAX_EVENTS 1 
#define MAX_BUF    1024 

// Simple single thread epoll server, that prints incoming requests to the stdout. 
int main() { 
int s; 
// create socket 
if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) { 
    perror("socket error"); 
    exit(1); 
} 

struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
int portno = 7000; 
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; // don't care IPv4 or IPv6 
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // receive packets destined to any of the interfaces 
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno); 

// by default, system doesn't close socket, but set it's status to TIME_WAIT; allow socket reuse    
int yes = 1; 
if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1) { 
    perror("setsockopt"); 
    exit(1); 
}  

// bind socket to address 
if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) == -1) { 
    perror("bind error"); 
    close(s); 
    exit(1); 
} 

// start listening on port 7000, allow only 1 connection in the incominq queue 
if (listen(s, 1) == -1) { 
    perror("listen error"); 
    close(s); 
    exit(1); 
} 

// create epoll instance 
int epfd; 
epfd = epoll_create(5); 
if (epfd == -1) { 
    perror("epoll_create"); 
} 

int cs; // client socket 
struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; 
socklen_t addr_size = sizeof their_addr; 

char request[MAX_BUF] = ""; 
struct epoll_event evlist[MAX_EVENTS]; 
while (strstr(request, "close") == NULL) { 
    // wait for incoming connection 
    if ((cs = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *) &their_addr, &addr_size)) == -1) { 
        perror("accept error"); 
        close(s); 
        exit(1); 
    } 

    struct epoll_event ev; 
    ev.data.fd = cs; 
    ev.events = EPOLLIN; 
    if (epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, cs, &ev) == -1) { 
        perror("epoll_ctl"); 
    } 
    int ready = epoll_wait(epfd, evlist, MAX_EVENTS, -1); 
    if (ready == -1) { 
        perror("epoll_wait"); 
    } 
    int j; 
    for (j = 0; j < ready; j++) { 
        char buf[MAX_BUF]; 
        int byte_count = read(evlist[j].data.fd, buf, MAX_BUF); 
        if (byte_count == -1) { 
            perror("read"); 
        } 
        memcpy(request, buf, byte_count); 
        puts(request); 
    } 

    char response[] =
     // Заголовок.
     "HTTP/1.1 200 OK \n Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8 \n Content-Length: 256 \n\n"
     // Тело HTML страницы.
     "<!doctype html>"
     "<html lang=\"en\">"
     "<head>"
        "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">"
        "<title>Document</title>"
     "</head>"
     "<body>"
        "ваш запрос: <strong>1</strong>"
     "</body>"
     "</html>\n";        
    if (send(cs, response, sizeof response, 0) == -1) { 
        perror("send error"); 
        close(s); 
        close(cs); 
        exit(1); 
    } 
    close(cs); 
}       
close(s); 
printf("Shutdown server... \n");
```

}

Comment: 1. ответ-ссылка. 2. вторая ссылка *уже* не работат.